# How to tell if a selection count has been called an even amount of times?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need a way to tell when the deslect count is equal to 0 an even amount of times. For example, if the count ==0 once dont do anything but if equals 0 twice then call the deselect nslog function. What is the best current way to make this work?

```
     if([self.mapView.selectedAnnotations count] == 0){

NSLog(@"DE SELECT");

}
```

Comment: may use count as NSMutableArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're always going to do the same thing on odd selections and the same other thing on even selections, just use a `static BOOL`.

```
if([self.mapView.selectedAnnotations count] == 0){
    static BOOL odd = YES;
    if(odd) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
    odd = !odd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your code needs to react to the user deselecting annoationations, you probably need to implement the mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView: method and add some logic that checks to see if the selection count has dropped to zero. If it has, increment a counter.